# Java/Swing: Mouse cursor doesn't change when over component

Tags: java, swing, cursor

in my application the mouse cursor does not change when over text field or other components (eg table resize).

The class MainWindow implements ActionListener and ListSelectionListener, could there be a cause? I never used MouseMotionListener or others.

Any ideas what could be the cause? Thanks

Edit:

Found cause: A panel containing the components was set disabled, the components worked fine, but the cursor didn't change when moving hover as the panel seems to be in charge of triggering that. maybe this post helps other lost souls

Comment: please give us the code you have in `implements`

Comment: Do you want to change default `Cursor` to custom when you under some component?

Comment: Components don't resize automatically, so the cursor will not change to support the resize cursors.

Comment: No custom cursors. I'm missing the default cursors that appears when you enter a component like a text field, or border of columnes of a table (sry, not the component itself). The cursors that tell the user, what he can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code (replace label_3 by your text field) :

```
Cursor cursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR); 
label_3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
frame.setCursor(cursor);
                }
}
```